# Dealing with asynchronous node_redis functions, awkward using INCR on two keys at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

Say my server is preparing a new object to send out in response to a POST request:

```
var responseObj = {
    UserID : "0", // default value
    ItemID : "0", // default value
    SomeData : foo
}
```

Now, when I create this new object, I want to increment the `UserId` and `ItemID` counters that I'm using in redis to track both items.  But that seemingly requires two separate asynchronous callbacks, which seems like a problem to me, because I can't just stick the rest of my response-writing code into one of the callbacks.

What I mean is, if I only had one key and one callback to worry about, I would write something like:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // do some pre-processing  

    var responseObj = {};      

    redis.incr('UserID', function(err, id) {
        responseObj.UserID = id;

        // do more work, write some response headers, etc.

        res.send(responseObj);
    });
}
```

But what do I do with two INCR callbacks I need to make?  I don't think this would be right, since everything is asynchronous and I can't guarantee my response would be correctly set...

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // do some pre-processing

    var responseObj = {};   

    redis.incr('UserID', function(err, id) {
        responseObj.UserID = id;
        // do some work
    });

    redis.incr('ItemID', function(err, id) {
        responseObj.ItemID = id;
        // do some work
    });

    res.send(responseObj); // This can't be right...
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, as a newbie node.js and redis programmer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute multiple redis commands in one call either through [transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) or [lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval). That way you won't have to deal with one callback per command, but rather execute multiple commands and deal only with one callback. For example try to look at [multi](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#clientmulticommands) method/command in redis client.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I wasn't understanding how the multi/exec pattern worked... I assumed the "results" argument that exec() gets invoked with was just going to be like the return values of calling incr() individually (i.e. true/false for success or failure).  Thanks.